# Контент вылазит за body html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему на телефонах появляется вот это белое пространство в проекте?
Код скинуть не могу, его слишком много. Прочекал всё через chrome tools, там нет никакого элемента. 
Кто сталкивался, может у кого-то было такое ? Как фиксить

Answer (score 1):

Что-то слишком широкое распирает или какой-то элемент расположен за границами основной полосы секций. Нужно пройтись по секциям и ставить `overflow: hidden` по очереди - как только исчезнет - сразу понятно в какой из секций баг, ее и можно будет проанализировать. Ну а можно и закостылить - оставив на ней `overflow: hidden`